# longtable in latex doesn't appear in list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

This longtable doesn't appear in the list of tables, I have tried some variants of captions but I couldn't get it to work.

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-7cm}{-2cm}
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{10cm}|}
    % \def\arraystretch{1.1}
    % \begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{9cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\centerline{Generating Inferences}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \centerline{Rule} & \centerline{Formula}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        \begin{center}
            Equality Resolution (ER)
        \end{center}
        &
         \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
            $s \not\simeq t \vee R$\\
            \hline
            $\sigma(R)$\\
            \\
            \end{tabular}
            \\
            $\text{if } \sigma = mgu(s,t) \text{ and } \sigma(s\not\simeq t) \text{ is eligible for resolution}$    
            \\
        \end{center} 
        \\
        \hline
        %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        \begin{center}
        Superposition into negative literals (SN)
        \end{center}
        &
         \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{c c}
                $s \simeq t \vee S$ & $u \not\simeq v \vee R$\\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\sigma(u[p \leftarrow \sigma(t)] \not\simeq v \vee S \vee R)$}\\
                \\
                \end{tabular}
                \\if $\sigma = mgu(u|_p,s)$, $\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(u) \not< \sigma(v)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, $\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, and $u|_p \not\in V$
                \\
                \end{center} 
        \\
        \hline
        %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        \begin{center}
        Superposition into positive literals (SP)
        \end{center}
        &
         \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{c c}
                $s \simeq t \vee S$ & $u \simeq v \vee R$\\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\sigma(u[p \leftarrow \sigma(t)] \simeq v \vee S \vee R)$}\\
                \\
                \end{tabular}
                \\
                if $\sigma = mgu(u|_p,s)$, $\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(u) \not< \sigma(v)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, $\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, and $u|_p \not\in V$
                \\
                \end{center} 
        \\
        \hline
        %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        \begin{center}
        Equality Factoring (EF)
        \end{center}
        &
         \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                $s \simeq t \vee u \simeq v \vee R$\\
                \hline
                $\sigma(t \not\simeq v \vee u \simeq v \vee R)$\\
                \\
                \end{tabular}
                \\
                if $\sigma = mgu(s,u)$, $\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$  is eligible for paramodulation.
                \\
                \end{center} 
        \\
        \hline
        \caption{Generating inference rules of the \textbf{SP} calculus implemented in E}
    \label{table:sp-ginference-rules}
\end{longtable}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code, not just a fragment?

Comment: Well, when I tried extracting this fragment from the project to create  a file with only this table it worked fine, given that I use \table and \tabular in the same project, would that be the reason?

Comment: You need to make a complete example that shows any problem that you want help with it's impossible to debug working code:-) start from a copy of the failing document and delete as much as you can, checking the problem still happens, then post the smallest document that you can make

Comment: I took the whole file from the project and put it in an empty one yet it's still working, and I have imported all of the packages from the whole project. I guess I will just delete the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to tell what's ailing your code, as you've only provided a code snippet but no `\listoftables` command, no indication of the document class that's in use, and no listing of the packages you employ.

At any rate, if I expand your code snippet to make it minimally compilable, the `longtable` does show up in the list of tables.

A suggestion: Do try to declutter and simplify your LaTeX code, possibly along the lines shown below. You'll find yourself writing both more quickly while being less prone to (coding) errors. Do also strive to give your tables a more open "look", e.g., by omitting all vertical lines and creating well-spaced horizontal lines (courtesy of the `booktabs` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath,array,booktabs}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mgu}{mgu}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth} % default: ca. 10cm
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{longtable}{@{} C{5cm}C{10cm} @{}}

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Generating Inferences}\\[1ex]
Rule & Formula\\
\midrule
\endhead

\addlinespace
\caption{Generating inference rules of the \textbf{SP} calculus implemented in E}
\label{table:sp-ginference-rules}
\endlastfoot

Equality Resolution (ER) &
$\begin{array}{c}
s\not\simeq t\vee R\\
  \hline
\sigma(R)
\end{array}$ \\[3ex]
& if $\sigma = \mgu(s,t)$ and 
$\sigma(s\not\simeq t)$ is eligible for resolution   
\\[1ex]

\midrule

Superposition into negative literals (SN) &
$\begin{array}{c c}
s \simeq t \vee S & u \not\simeq v \vee R\\
  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
    \sigma(u[\,p\to\sigma(t)]\not\simeq v\vee S\vee R)}
\end{array}$ \\[3ex]
& if $\sigma = \mgu(u|_p,s)$, 
$\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, 
$\sigma(u) \not< \sigma(v)$, 
$\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, 
$\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, 
and $u|_p \not\in V$
\\[1ex]

\midrule

Superposition into positive literals (SP) &
$\begin{array}{cc}
s \simeq t \vee S & u \simeq v \vee R\\
  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
    \sigma(u[\,p \to \sigma(t)]\simeq v\vee S\vee R)}
\end{array}$ \\[3ex]
& if $\sigma = \mgu(u|_p,s)$, 
$\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, 
$\sigma(u) \not< \sigma(v)$, 
$\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, 
$\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, 
and $u|_p \not\in V$
\\[1ex]

\midrule

Equality Factoring (EF)
&
$\begin{array}{c}
s \simeq t \vee u \simeq v \vee R\\
  \hline
\sigma(t \not\simeq v \vee u \simeq v \vee R)
\end{array}$ \\[3ex]
& if $\sigma = \mgu(s,u)$, 
$\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, 
$\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation.
\\[1ex]
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, I have no prblem with the list of tables. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, and took the liberty to slightly modify the layout of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ignoremp]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx, ltablex, caption}%{l}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

 \begin{document}

 \listoftables
 \bigskip
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\keepXColumns
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.67\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.33\hsize}X|}
        \caption{Generating inference rules of the \textbf{SP} calculus implemented in E}
 \label{table:sp-ginference-rules}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Generating Inferences}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        Rule & Formula\\
        \hline
        \hline
\endfirsthead
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Generating Inferences}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        Rule & Formula\\
        \hline
        \hline
\endhead
 \hline
\endfoot
        %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            Equality Resolution (ER)
        & $ \begin{matrix}
            s \not\simeq t \vee R\\
            \hline
            \sigma(R)
            \end{matrix} $\medskip\newline
\parbox{\hsize}{if $ \sigma = mgu(s,t) $ and $ \sigma(s\not\simeq t) $ is eligible for resolution.}\smallskip
        \\
        \hline
 %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Superposition into negative literals (SN)
 & $ \begin{matrix}
 s \simeq t \vee S & u \not\simeq v \vee R \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\sigma(u[p \leftarrow \sigma(t)] \not\simeq v \vee S \vee R)}
 \end{matrix} $ \medskip\newline
\parbox{\hsize}{if $\sigma = mgu(u|_p,s)$, $\sigma(s) \nless \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(u) \nless \sigma(v)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, $\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, and $u|_p \notin V$.}\smallskip
 \\
 \hline
 %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Superposition into positive literals (SP)
 &$ \begin{matrix}
 s \simeq t \vee S & u \simeq v \vee R \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\sigma(u[p \leftarrow \sigma(t)] \simeq v \vee S \vee R)}
 \end{matrix} $
 \medskip\newline
\parbox{\hsize}{if $\sigma = mgu(u|_p,s)$, $\sigma(s) \nless \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(u) \nless \sigma(v)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation, $\sigma(u \not\simeq v)$ is eligible for resolution, and $u|_p \notin V$.}\smallskip
 \\
 \hline
 %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Equality Factoring (EF)
 & $ \begin{matrix}
 s \simeq t \vee u \simeq v \vee R\\
 \hline
\sigma(t \not\simeq v \vee u \simeq v \vee R)
 \end{matrix}$ \medskip\newline
\parbox{\hsize}{ if $\sigma = mgu(s,u)$, $\sigma(s) \not< \sigma(t)$, $\sigma(s \simeq t)$ is eligible for paramodulation.}\medskip
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Oh! yes. It's a residue of my first trial: I hadn't removed `\centerline`s from the O.P.'s code, which made `tabularx` overflow into the margin, and I didn't understand why. Thanks for pointing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

you have used `\caption[]` the empty optional argument there is specifically to prevent the caption being in the table of contents,

Comment: even if I delete it, it still doesn't appear in the list of tables

Comment: @AhmedAnwar are you sure? (you would need to run latex twice) but please fix the example so people can test it